# ImageView zoom and set another image problem

Tags: java, android, imageview, pinchzoom

**I have succeeded to zoom imageView by this site idea:**

> https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/
>
> **the problem that appears to me now is:
> i use an next and previous buttons to load images in the same image view
> when that done the new image *loaded zoomed in*.
> i need to view it in normal size and let user to zoom it if he want.**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class MyTouchImageView extends ImageView {
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    private  static final int NONE = 0;
    private  static final int DRAG = 1;
    private  static final int CLICK = 3;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private float origWidth, origHeight;
    private Matrix matrix;
    private  int mode = NONE;
    private PointF last = new PointF();
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private  float minScale = 1f;
    private float maxScale = 3f;
    private  float[] m;
    private  int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    private float saveScale = 1f;
    private  int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    private  Context context;

    public MyTouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public MyTouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
   matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        setMinimumHeight(800);
        setMinimumWidth(1000);
  
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();


            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

LOADING IMAGE

```
private MyTouchImageView Title_images;
    Title_images = findViewById(R.id.title_image); 
    Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(StudentInsideExam.this)).load(examInsideDatas.get(ShownPointIndexInArray).getImageUrls()).into(Title_images);
```

XML:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ayman.learningway.MyTouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:background="@color/tan_background"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid using the same scale of the previous image when you navigate to the next image, you need to reset the previous image to its original scale.

If you notice when you first load your image into your `MyTouchImageView`, it loads with its original scale which is normally (1f), you can find that in the `MyTouchImageView` with the statement `private float saveScale = 1f;`

Also when you pinch zoom your image, then `onScale()` of the `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` within the `MyTouchImageView` is triggered.

So what you need to do to reset the image to its original scale is to reverse the last operation happened within `onScale()`. Which is normally allows you to back to a scale of 1f.

To to that add the below method to your `MyTouchImageView`:

```
public void resetToOriginalScale() {

    // reverse the operation happened on onScale() method
    float scaleFactor = (float) 1.0 / saveScale;
    // reset the scale to the original scale
    saveScale = 1f;
    matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);

    fixTrans();

    // Simulating a touch event within the ImageView in order to allow it to redraw with the original scale
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            0,
            0,
            metaState
    );

    dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);

}
```

Then whenever you navigate to a new image, you first need to reset the scale of the current image by calling `resetToOriginalScale()`:

```
mImageView = findViewById(R.id.title_image);
mImageView.resetToOriginalScale();
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(new_image_url).centerCrop().into(mImageView);
```

Use `.centerCrop()` with all your Glide invocations.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: THANK IT WORKS,but something is wrong here,if an image is taller than other the height change so the content below the image not appear below the image directly,and that appears to me from the background color of the image.

Comment: i can describewhat i mean in this image: > https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learning-way.appspot.com/o/descripeproblem.jpg?alt=media&token=e6faad6b-35c1-4cf8-8099-309d5fde689a

Comment: @Ayman.dev please try to use `Glide.with(this).load(myImage).centerCrop().into(mImageView);` in all your usages of Glide .. hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Ayman.dev please check updated answer with `matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                viewHeight / 2);` within `the backToOriginalScale()`, it totoally solves the problem; also check my last comment

Comment: when using: >matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2); nothing change >but when changing Glide.with(this).load(myImage).centerCrop().into(mImageView); it works and come back to original but i found that apart of the image in right and left disappears  and It does not come back even by zoom in or out.

Comment: @Ayman.dev can you try to remove `.centerCrop()` from all Glide's and test, I mean all Glide have the same parameters

Comment: it does not work and the change to the backToOriginalScale() also

Comment: ok i used: > .fitCenter() instead of .centerCrop() the result is seems satisfy to me ,thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Ayman.dev you're welcome .. If my answer was useful, please click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others who have similar questions.

Comment: already done but it tells me: > Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score,you can give my quiz checkmark (✓) to push me

Comment: Hi @Ayman.dev [Accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) is something different than [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)/[downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) it, you may check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .. Up/down vote requires minimum reputation, but accepting answer doesn't .. Following this will keep people help one another with no frustration or laziness to support.. and also help people that have the same / similar question of yours

Comment: please check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on#answer-251298) as a newbie

Comment: It seems that when i accepted your answer ,my reputation increased enough to upvote to your answer